# Intellij No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium, intellij-idea

[image]

I installed selenium through the command line and imported the library on Intellij. At first glance, it seems to be fine, because the software returns "unused import statement"  Unfortunately when I use the module in any way it returns an error. No module named 'selenium'

I tried to `pip install selenium` again, and got

> Requirement already satisfied: selenium in
>   c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

This is the code I was trying to run:

```
import selenium

help(selenium)
```

which returns the same error. It does not say the module does

[image]

not exist before

[image]

I run the code like it would if I would just write random import.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the project interpreter for this project is configured to use your system Python. [The JetBrains documentation for doing this is here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) In IntelliJ, essentially you need to go to the project structure settings and configure the Python SDK for the project or module (whichever is needed).<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Instructions will vary if you are using a different JetBrains IDE than IntelliJ, but this is what you specified in your question.</sub>

Comment: But in the SDK I applied the classpath specified above. And the problem seemed to be solved. Although before I run the program it recognizes the library. Only when I try to run it, it does not work.

Comment: Did you run it through IntelliJ or from command line / outside the tool?

Comment: Through Intellij.

Comment: @Shlomi and you're *sure* your Python path that corresponds to pip is the same as the one used by PyCharm in the settings? I.e. the actual Python binary is in the Scripts folder and is pointed to as the SDK and the packages for *that* Python instance contain the dependency? No alternate system version in root of C:\ or anything....

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy5m7.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxAHL.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0jDY.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC32G.jpg

I have added these images for you to better understand the problem.

Comment: You can see very clearly in the images that those two versions of Python are in completely different file paths and are thus not the same. Just as I said. IntelliJ has a different path than the path used in the terminal. It is configured incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah you are right I was not paying attention I need to configure every time I open the IDE. Again, when the right classpath in the project structure is configured, same error occurs. I guess you are referring to a different type of configuration.